# Category as static library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to build an Objective-C static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654534/how-to-build-an-objective-c-static-library)

I'm creating a category of `UIWebView` and I want to make that category as a static library because I don't want to share that particular code. So is it possible? If yes then how or are there any other ways then please suggest that. Any help is appreciable.

Comment: But the link you have provided it is showing the usual way to create a normal static library but I trying to create a category of UIWebView as a static library to hide source code.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your code is just categories, or real classes. You would build a static library from it in exactly the same way. If there is some specific problem you're having with the process, please tell us what it is.

Comment: Thanks, I've created a static library and defined a method but while I'm calling that method using uiwebview instance it is showing unrecognized selector for instance xxxxxx. Is there any path settings required I don't have very much exp. about those so please suggest me. Now I'm trying only for simulator.

Comment: See this note [Building Objective-C static libraries with categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html). You need to add linkers flag `-ObjC` and `-all_load`.

Comment: Do I've to create separate libraries for device and simulator. In the following link It is mention to merge. Can we do this?
http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/