# objective c secure header file

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, privacy

Is there a way to create a header file containing some methods without others being able to get to the definition of my methods inside .m files? For example, you can't access method definitions of the ones written by apple(i.e you go to `UIImage.h` and when you want to see the definition of one of those methods you can't).

So basically what I want to do, is hide the .m file from the other developers. The developers can see only the .h file.

Comment: Who is your "user"? The end customer shouldn't see the sources. Do you develop code, which is a part of another (the "user's") project?

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question.

Comment: If you do not want the users to see your .m file, don't give it to them. Give them a [static library](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4654534/335858) that you compile plus a header, and leave it at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to build the code into a static library or framework and deploy that. It contains all of the executable (.m file) code and allows access only to the .h files.

Read about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html).