# Creating an universal library in Xcode8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, xcode8

I have successfully created a .a library file for my xcode project and now i need to create the universal library in xcode 8. I am follwing the tutorials in:

[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654534/how-to-build-an-objective-c-static-library)

and

[Raywanderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/41377/creating-a-static-library-in-ios-tutorial)

But since i am using the xcode8.2 i cannot see any aggregate template to create the universal static library . Please see the screenshot. So please tell me how to create an universal library in XCode8.2

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per New `XCode` you can find **aggregate** under Add Target Option as below

> Add Target -> Cross Platform -> aggregate

**Look at below screenshots :**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that this is the spot you get to by clicking on the blue project icon in the Project Navigator.